# Capturing multiple cookies in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

**Edit** 
The cookies in the example come from a curl request

Original question:
I want get all the different cookies from php and then use chrome addon to set the cookie on a website

```
Set-Cookie: ref_code=__default__; expires=Wed, 07-Jan-2026 07:55:57 GMT; Max-Age=315359999; path=/; domain=.somesite.com; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: usertype=Unlogged-User; expires=Wed, 07-Jan-2026 07:55:57 GMT; Max-Age=315359999; path=/; domain=.somesite.com; secure
```

The following code will get the cookie but won't include the expires , Max-Age directive etc... but i would need all of those as well

```
 preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
        //var_dump($matches);
        $cookies = array();
        foreach ($matches[1] as $item) {
            parse_str($item, $cookie);
            $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
        }
```

I `json_encode` the `$cookies` array and then i pass it to the extension.

Taking into account that `chrome.cookie` has parameters set in the following order, how can i get all cookies efficiently  with php and then manipulate the json with js to set the cookie

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the question by adding an example scenario noting what you want to do in php, js, because to me this sounds a little bit inside-out. If you have the php code that sends the cookie via a Set-Cookie header, then why do you need the php code to parse the Set-Cookie header? Just create the $cookie array "parallel" to the code that sends the cookie, there you have all the values you want, just pack them to $cookies the way you want

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "*" to the regex:

```
^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*;)*([^;]*)$
```

Without that it ends at the 1st ";"

If there is always at least 1 space after Set-Cookie:, then this seems to work:

```
preg_match_all("/\s+([^;]*;)/", $result, $matches);
```

Comment: its definitely possible.I am thinking of regex to get the expires , Max Age , Path etc.. from the Set-cookie .The regex is quite complex though

Comment: I don't think it is possible, or I misunderstood the question. I thought you want to get the cookies from the browser. If you know how to get it, then please add the code to the question. Or is the question about how to parse the Set-Cookie http header STRING(that you have from somewhere?) with all it's optional parameters?

Comment: The latter is correct the cookies come from curl and the question is about how to  parse the Set-Cookie http header

Comment: @user2650277 why i stil have the -1 ?